# Playing ulaw file with QAudioOutput

Tags: qt, audio

I'm trying to set up a simple working example to play a .raw file and the audio seems to be distorted. When the .raw file plays, I can still make out everything, its just fairly distorted, like listening to a radio station going out of range.

```
QString mResourcePath ="test.raw";
QFile audio_file(mResourcePath);
 if(audio_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
     audio_file.seek(4); // skip wav header
     QByteArray audio_data = audio_file.readAll();
     audio_file.close();

     QBuffer audio_buffer(&audio_data);
     audio_buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
     qDebug() << audio_buffer.size();

     QAudioFormat format;

     format.setSampleSize(8);
     format.setSampleRate(8000);
     format.setChannelCount(1);
     format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
     format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::BigEndian);
     format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);


     QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultOutputDevice());
     if (!info.isFormatSupported(format)) {
         qWarning()<<"raw audio format not supported by backend, cannot play audio.";

         return;
     }
     qDebug() << info.deviceName();

     QAudioOutput output(info, format);
     output.start(&audio_buffer);

     // ...then wait for the sound to finish
     QEventLoop loop;
     QObject::connect(&output, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
     do {
        loop.exec();
     } while(output.state() == QAudio::ActiveState);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question indicates that you wish to play u-law audio, which is logarithmic PCM. Yet, the line

```
format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
```

initializes playback for linear PCM. 2 possible solutions:

1. Initialize playback with the appropriate log PCM codec. The docs report that [QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaudiodeviceinfo.html#supportedCodecs) will return a list of supported codecs.
2. Convert the log PCM samples to linear PCM in real time. It's pretty low impact and can be performed using a lookup table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!

If I use QAudioDeviceInfo::supportedCodecs() I only get "audio/pcm"

I'm new in programming and I have no ideea how to convert the log PCM samples to linear PCM in real time. Can you give me a hint.

Thank you!!

Comment: This source code might be of some use: http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavcodec/pcm_tablegen.h

Comment: Do you have any ideea how can I play the converted data? I tryed with QAudioOutput::start () but I get "Invalid conversion from qint16{aka short int} to "IODevice""

Comment: I'm not versed on qt. This sounds like it should be a separate Stack Overflow question.